# C# reading a file and display in a table

Tags: c#

My objective is to read a text file and display the content in a table.
I have been through a lot of forum and goggling and still couldnt find a solution.

My Table format:

```
<table >

   <`tr>

      <`td>

         Australia

      <`/td>

      <`td>

         <`table>

            <`tr>

               <`td>

                  1

               <`/td>

            <`/tr>

         <`/table>

       <`/tr>

<`/table>
```

My TextFile look like:

```
Australia = 1,1,2,2

Malaysia = 1,1,1,2,2,2

Singapore = 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2
```

My Reading code:

```
        string path = @"..\TestFile.txt";
        char token = ',';
        char token2 = '=';

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        Response.Write("<table>");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] country = line.Split(token2);
            string[] image = line.Split(token);
            string row = "<tr><td>" + country + "</td>" +"<table><tr>";
            Response.Write(row);
            for (int i = 0; i < image.Length; i++)
            {   

                string row2 = "<td>" + image[i] +"</td>";
                Response.Write(row2);
            }
            Response.Write("</tr></table>");
        }
        Response.Write("</tr></table>");
```

my result:

```
System.String[]
Australia = 1   1   2   2
System.String[]
Malaysia = 1    1   1   2   2   2
System.String[]
Singapore = 1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2
```

and what i want to achieve :

```
Australia    1     1    2    2

Malaysia     1     1    1    2    2    2

Singapore    1     1    1    1    2    2    2    2
```

any help would be appreciated . Thanks!

Comment: @MR. dissapointment, think we should compile and complete it for him ;)

Comment: im sorry for the trouble, been trying for a long time =[

Comment: the splitting is not right as the Australia doesnt split with 1
as in the table looks like 

 | Australia 1 | 1 | 1 |

and i would need it to look like 

 | Australia | 1| 1| 1|

Comment: @foo: A hint: debug this and check the type of `country` and value of `image[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. questions solved =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood problem correctly, try to do like this:

```
string[] country = line.Split(token2);
string[] image = country[1].Split(token); //<- take string after = symbol, and split it
string row = "<tr><td>" + country[0] + "</td>" +"<table><tr>"; //<- take first string before = symbol
```

Comment: Thanks ! this solved the problem =] 
but how can i do it in a two dimensional array?

Comment: That's another question. :) But I think you should store everything in List or Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

From quickly reading the question, it appears you have been able to split/parse the content and are only asking for a way to format the output.

This can be achieved using `String.PadLeft()` or `String.PadRight()`. Alternatively `String.Format("{0,-10}", stringValue)`.

HTH,

**References**

- [System.String.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft.aspx)
- [System.String.PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx)
- [Align String With Spaces](http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/)